# Show more/Show less javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use this code for show more / show less function. Why is it not working? Here is index.html

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.more').click(); // this will trigger the alert
        },10);
        $(".show-more button").on("click", function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var $content = $this.parent().prev("div.content");
            var linkText = $this.text().toUpperCase();
    
            if(linkText === "SHOW MORE"){
                linkText = "Show less";
                $content.switchClass("hideContent", "showContent", 400);
            } else {
                linkText = "Show more";
                $content.switchClass("showContent", "hideContent", 400);
            };
    
            $this.text(linkText);
        });
    });
```

```css
    div.text-container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 75%;    
    }
    
    .hideContent {
        overflow: hidden;
        line-height: 1em;
        height: 2em;
    }
    
    .showContent {
        line-height: 1em;
        height: auto;
    }
    .showContent{
        height: auto;
    }
    
    h1 {
        font-size: 24px;        
    }
    p {
        padding: 10px 0;
    }
    .show-more {
        padding: 10px 0;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
    <div class="text-container">
        <div class="content hideContent">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
         <p>Some more text</p>
         <ul>
          <li>Some more text</li>
          <li>Some more text</li>
          <li>Some more text</li>
         </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="show-more">
         <button>Show more</button>
        </div>
       </div>
```

Comment: switchClass() is not part of jquery , to use this you have to use `jqueryUI`

Comment: JSFiddle adds the html, head and body tags automatically. Your code conflicts with it and therefore your code is not working.

Comment: I tried it in my own files aswell, and i used jQueryUI from https://code.jquery.com/ui/ but its still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong selector and swichtclass, change it to `$(".content").toggleClass`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.more').click(); // this will trigger the alert
    },10);
    $(".show-more button").on("click", function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $content = $this.parent().prev("div.content");
        var linkText = $this.text()

        if(linkText === "show-more"){
            linkText = "Show less";
            $(".content").toggleClass("hideContent", "showContent", 400);
        } else {
            linkText = "Show more";
            $(".content").toggleClass("showContent", "hideContent", 400);
        };

        $this.text(linkText);
    });
});
```

```css
div.text-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 75%;    
}

.hideContent {
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 1em;
    height: 2em;
}

.showContent {
    line-height: 1em;
    height: auto;
}
.showContent{
    height: auto;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 24px;        
}
p {
    padding: 10px 0;
}
.show-more {
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascrpit" src="js/test.js"></script>
<div class="text-container">
                <div class="content hideContent">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
                    <p>Some more text</p>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Some more text</li>
                        <li>Some more text</li>
                        <li>Some more text</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="show-more">
                    <button>Show more</button>
                </div>
            </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

refer this link : http://jsfiddle.net/Wpn94/2131/

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a little change in html structure

```
<html>
 <head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
   </script>
  </head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascrpit" src="js/test.js"></script>
<div class="text-container">
 <div class="content hideContent">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.

    <div class="show-this-extra">
        <p>Some more text</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Some more text</li>
            <li>Some more text</li>
            <li>Some more text</li>
        </ul>    
        <button class="show-less">Show less</button>
    </div>      
  </div>
  <button class="show-more">Show more</button>
</div>
```

Edit your test js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".show-this-extra").hide();
    $(".show-more").on("click",function(){
        $(".show-this-extra").show();
        $(".show-more").hide();
    });
    $(".show-less").on("click",function(){
        $(".show-this-extra").hide();
        $(".show-more").show();
    });
});
```